# using cron to run script

Tags: linux, rhel, python, cron

Hey guys, im trying to run a script using cron, im using a crontab created by the user ashtanga, in the crontab i have

```
*/5 * * * *  /home/custom-django-projects/SiteMonitor/sender.py
```

in top of the script i have:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

and the user ashtanga does have executable permission to the file, but cron is not running the script, its giving me the error:

```
/bin/sh: /home/custom-django-projects/SiteMonitor/sender.py: No such file or directory
```

so my question is, how can i get cron to run the script ?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file? Can you paste the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 431 Jan  7 19:42 sender.py

Comment: what's `readlink -f sender.py` output.

Comment: @ xenoterracide i ran it from root and this was the output /home/custom-django-apps/SiteMonitor/sender.py

Comment: wow, i just noticed that i was trying to access the wrong directory by looking at the output from readlink -f sender.py and the error message, it now works !!,  thanks a lot guys for taking the time to help, i really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user does have permission as the permission is set to 755
The problem is that the user doesn't know of the environment variables needed.
Try using bash instead and see if it picks them up then. Otherwise, set them up manually

Start troubleshooting by running the script using the `/bin/sh` shell. You should get the same error then.

Comment: i tried exporting the SHELL variable and changing it to /bin/sh and then ran the script from the user ashtanga, and it didn't throw an error

Comment: Did you try logging in as ashtanga running this command  /bin/sh /home/custom-django-projects/SiteMonitor/sender.py  ?

Comment: thanks, i just tried it and yes it gave me the same error, what do can i do so that it finds it

Comment: If the permissions were the problem, the error would be `Permission denied`, even if it was some intermediate directory that was unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The user `ashtanga` doesn't have access to `/home/custom-django-projects/SiteMonitor/sender.py`. This looks like another user's home area?

Try running the script as `ashtanga`. It's always a good first step, before you add anything to cron.

It might be to do with your cron environment. Take a look at this [Cron FAQ: It works from the command line but not in crontab](http://www.unix.com/answers-frequently-asked-questions/13527-cron-crontab.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, as recommended by you i tried running the script as ashtanga, first like this: /home/custom-django-apps/SiteMonitor/sender.py , and then with a python in front of the directory, and both times were succesfull, but cron still cant run it

Comment: try changing your cron to: `*/5 * * * *  ls -ltr /home/custom-django-projects/SiteMonitor/sender.py 2>&1 > /tmp/test.log` and see what it prints in the log

Comment: nothin in the logs, all i got was a mail from cron with the following error ls: /home/custom-django-projects/SiteMonitor/sender.py: No such file or directory